# How to publish OSQA on azure?

Tags: python, django, azure, osqa

Can anyone help me to publish [OSQA application](https://github.com/OSQA/osqa) to windows azure ?
I want to publish my osqa applicatoin to azure but I can not find any proper solution.
Some solution I found but they are not useful to me.
some of the site which I have find are as follows

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/

[Installing OSQA on windows (local system)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743712/installing-osqa-on-windows-local-system)

please help me to find some proper solution that can work for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question - but in case anyone comes across it, Bitnami put together an image that is available in the VM Depot in Azure.

https://bitnami.com/stack/osqa/cloud/azure

Really easy to deploy if you are already using Azure. The Azure portal will walk you through copying the image to your subscription, then you just have to register it and deploy a VM from that image.